# How to properly deal with java interface in different package?

Tags: java, interface

I'm new to Java and I've got a package for interfaces. Each interface has a number of imports for the types used in the interface declarations.

```
// MyInterface.java...

package a.b.c.interfaces;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public interface MyInterface() { ...
```

Then I've got a package with models, and inside of it, I'm attempting to create a class that implements `MyInterface()`.

```
// MyImplementation.java...

package a.b.c.models;

public class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {...
```

I have two questions:

1. Does `MyInterface()` need to be imported into
   `MyImplementation()`? If not, does it then need to be linked
   manually during compilation?
2. If `MyInterface()` is imported, is
   it also necessary to import the types the interface requires, or
   does the import of `MyInterface.java` take care of this?

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: @ScaryWombat: trial-and-error vs. reaching out to a super knowledgable community who can provide specifics.  I chose the latter. Plus I couldn't find any good StackOverflow Q's regarding imports of interface across packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imports in Java is basically a way of telling the compiler that when you write `MyInterface` you really mean `a.b.c.interfaces.MyInterface`. It is definitely possible to write Java code without using imports but it is extremely verbose and looks messy.

You need to import any type that you want to use that is not in the same package as the class you're writing or in `java.lang` so since `MyInterface` is in `a.b.c.interfaces` and `MyImplementation` in `a.b.c.model` you need to import it.

You do need to import the classes that `MyInterface` is using if you're writing their *type* anywhere in your code - and since you're implementing the interface you will need to write their types in your method declarations. There is no way of using the same imports as another class in Java.

Here is an example of usage of types where we don't need to import them:

UsesBigInteger.java:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class UsesBigInteger {
    public BigInteger get() {
        return BigInteger.TEN;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
     public static void Main(String[] args) {
          UsesBigInteger use = new UsesBigInteger();
          System.out.println(use.get());
     }
}
```

The reason we don't have to import `java.math.BigInteger` here is that we never actually write `BigInteger` anywhere so we don't need to tell the compiler what we mean by that - we just pass the return value from `UsesBigInteger.get()` along and the compiler already knows that that is a `java.math.BigInteger`.

If we want to keep a reference to the `BigInteger` we need to import it though:

Main.java

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
     public static void Main(String[] args) {
          UsesBigInteger use = new UsesBigInteger();
          BigInteger it = use.get();
          System.out.println(it);
     }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Ans for your first question, you have to import the interface and on class you have to implement your interface.

As for your second question, you just need to import `MyInterface`. The JVM will take care of the rest.

I strongly suggest you to go threw the oops concepts as its too basic question.

And also use any IDE like Eclipse.

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what 'import' means in Java.  No you don't need to import the interface if you do not want, and there is no "the rest" for the JVM to take care of.  Import only save your typing.

Comment: Before answering please read the question carefully. He just want to implement a interface and please clear the point the import only locate the path of file which you are giving directly here and yes there is rest which JVM take cares which is ur class object... That which class is mapped to which interface and what methods we can use in it

Comment: Even you are NOT importing, JVM is going to take care of the same thing.  Hence that are not "the rest" of import that JVM is taking care of.  Import, from what I understand, is simply meaningful to the *COMPILER* but not the Java Runtime (aka JVM)